# XML:Twig perform multiple twig handlers on file

Tags: xml, perl

I have the following problem: I need to modify an xml file using 4 or 5 twig handlers. Currently, each time I parse one of the twig handlers over the file I then need to save the file before being able to parse the next handler over the now modified data. This requires that I keep having to save the file for each handler. Is there a way to open the file once, run all the handlers one after the other and then save the file at the end?

The reason I need this is that I am hoping it will speed up my program that currently uses the above procedure thousands of times and therefore opens and closes a lot of files. I was thinking that if I have n handlers for a specific file and m files then I need to perform the file saving n*m times. I would like to be able to divide this number by n.

I have looked at the parsefile_inplace option in xml twig but cannot get it to work!

Additional: I should have mentioned that the running of certain twig handlers in the chain depends on the results from previous handlers and therefore not all handlers can be run together in a single statement.

Many thanks.

Comment: Note there is a [`sprint`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig#XML::Twig) method that returns the document as text (i.e. a string). Then you could reparse the text (using `parse`) instead of saving to file?

Comment: Do you have to use handlers?